# how to resize the image through imshow (opencv , imshow )?

Tags: c++, opencv, resize, imshow

I am trying to show an image. but imshow shows the image with big scales so that I can see the image's pixels(as shown in the image below)[image]

as you see pixels are too big. and it is not nice. I expected something like this:

[image]

is there any way to resize the image's window size?
I am using Linux vscode

here is my code:

```
int main()
{
     Mat O_image = imread("lena.jpg");

     namedWindow("hamid", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
     imshow("hamid", O_image);
     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
}
```

the pointer changes when I move the mouse to the edges but I can't resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cv::namedWindow with [WindowFlags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3) to control the size of the output window.

```
cv::Mat img;
img = cv::imread("Lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

cv::namedWindow("A image of Lena", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); //CV_WINDOW_NORMAL to enable the user to resize the window
cv::imshow("A image of Lena", img);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer . the pointer changes when I go near the edges but I still can't resize it .

Comment: Are you using cv::waitKey(0) after cv::imshow? Did you try the other WindowFlags like CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO? Can you show the small piece of code?

Comment: Can you try waitKey() and waitKey(1)? I heard that this is also sometimes an issue. I cannot reproduce to error since I am mainly not working with Linux.